# Why is Python class variable acting like a static variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a node class like this:

```
  def __init__(self, data, incoming = [], outgoing = []):
    self.data = data
    self.incoming = incoming
    self.outgoing = outgoing

  def addIncoming(self, incoming):
    self.incoming.append(incoming)

  def addOutgoing(self, outgoing):
    self.outgoing.append(outgoing)
```

where every instance was initialized like `Node(number)` so the incoming and outgoing parameters were defaulted to an empty list. I also had functions that appended other nodes to the incoming and outgoing list but when I did that, it was appending to every instance. For example lets say I had `a=Node(1)` and `b=Node(2)`. If I did `a.addIncoming(b)` and printed `a.incoming` and `b.incoming`, they both would print `Node b`. Why are these values shared between separate instances?

When I updated my init function to be

```
  def __init__(self, data, incoming = [], outgoing = []):
    self.data = data
    self.incoming = []
    self.outgoing = []
```

everything worked as expected but I feel like the two should work the same. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a class. Default parameter values are only evaluated once. This means that `[]` there creates only one list object for all function calls and object instances.

Comment: There are enough differences between this question and the linked duplicate that I thought it deserved to remain open.

Comment: Dang, I keep forgetting the dupe-hammer works in both directions.

Comment: Read [Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Comment: @MarkRansom what "differences"? It's exactly the same problem, and has been covered in great detail on the canonical post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe half the problem in that post is caused by returning a list from the function.  This question involves `__init__` from which nothing gets returned.

Comment: @MarkRansom that's just the way in which you see the problem manifest, the binding behaviour is identical. Also there *are* class-based examples in the dupe's answers. Your answer doesn't touch on any such distinction at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To me the questions are clearly different, even if the same explanation suffices for both.  I've never thought that a dupe should be defined by duplicate answers rather than duplicate questions.

Comment: @MarkRansom that's *exactly* what defines a dupe, we're trying to get people to the content that answers their question. Your claim that the OP needs a specific solution to their unique problem would ring a lot truer if you'd bothered to provide one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe compare the answer I left on that other question to the answer I left here, and tell me how similar they are.  That answer would be completely out of place here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default parameters are evaluated when the function *is defined*, and stored with the function.  So `__init__` gets those empty lists, but every time you modify them the modifications are saved.

Remember that in Python, making new assignments with `=` does *not* make a copy of the data.  Those lists are shared with every assignment you make.